# How to play azure video without using plugin

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using html5 video tag but still I cannot play my azure video in IE 11,ipad,safari...i am using this below mentioned plugin to play my video in all the browser and to play in IE.

**Plugin used to play video in IE:**

```
amp.options.flashSS.swf = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/StrobeMediaPlayback.2.0.swf" 

amp.options.flashSS.plugin = "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/techs/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-osmf2.0.swf" .
```

so my question is How can I play my video in IE and safari without installing flash player and adding this plugin ??

Comment: What format does your video have? If it is a flash video (.swf) you need a plugin. If it is encoded in some supported codec (browser dependent) then the video tag is fine. If it is a DASH video (using H.264 codec) then you may look into DASH.js player

Comment: Have you had a look at Azure Media player?